# Allowing Query Options in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata

I am trying to narrow down the data I get from Microsoft Graph. When I try to use $filter or $count or $search or any other such options, I get an error message "

OData Version: 3 and 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (The query specified in the URI is not valid. Query option 'Count' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.)"

My question is where and how do I set the "AllowedQueryOptions". I am not very knowledgeable about Microsoft Graph so I would appreciate a little simplicity and more clarity.

Comment: Could you share the url including query parameters? It's not possible to say what's wrong without more details.

Answer (score 0):

The query options for Use query parameters to customize responses with the different options:

For $filter parameter please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) and for advance queries search parameter refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http).
[image]

For $count parameter please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#count-parameter).

For $search parameter please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#select-parameter).

For OData version 4.0, Check [OData V4 query language](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752356) for more details
[image]

Hope this is helpful.